# Lighttpd cannot create php-fastcgi.socket

Tags: php, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have installed FastCGI using yum, and edited my lighttpd.conf, but when restarting the server I receive this error.

```
2009-06-24 12:44:43: (log.c.97) server started 
2009-06-24 12:44:43: (mod_fastcgi.c.924) bind failed for: unix:/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket-0 No such file or directory 
2009-06-24 12:44:43: (mod_fastcgi.c.1365) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed. 
2009-06-24 12:44:43: (server.c.902) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

The concerned part of my lighttpd.conf is:

```
fastcgi.server             = ( ".php" =>
                               ( "localhost" =>
                                 (
                                  #"socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket",
                                  #"bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
                                   "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket",
                                   "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
                                 )
                               )
                            )
```

Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that lighttpd has permission to write to  /var/run/lighttpd

Answer (score 2):

**Got Fixed with following changes:**

- `mkdir /var/run/lighttpd`
- `touch /var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket`
- `chown -R lighttpd:lighttpd /var/run/lighttpd`

*Where lighttpd is the username.*

Updating socket in lighttpd.conf to point to /var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket solves the problem.

[unix:/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket-0 No such file or directory](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/1718)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with `/var/run/lighttpd` set owned by `www-data` by something instead of `lighttpd` user. I added the `lighttpd` user to the `www-data` group but apparently things still don't work sometimes, so I overrided the systemd service script with `systemctl edit lighttpd`:

```yaml
/etc/systemd/system/lighttpd.service.d/override.conf
-----------------------------------------
[Unit]
Description=Lighttpd Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown lighttpd:lighttpd /var/log/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/lighttpd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown lighttpd:lighttpd /var/run/lighttpd
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
mkdir -p /var/run/lighttpd/
chown lighttpd /var/run/lighttpd
```

See http://www.kernelhardware.org/lighttpd-and-centos-5/

Answer (score 0):

```
touch /tmp/php-fastcgi.socket
```

Just create the file with the above command.

EDIT: Either your using old log output or your conf is newer. Either way create /var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket-0 or the above.

Ta

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the /tmp/php-fastcgi.socket file exists, and if it doesn't, run

```
# touch /tmp/php-fastcgi.socket
```

then make sure the permissions and ownership/groups are set right with chmod/chown/chgrp. On my server that'd be:

```
# chmod 664 /tmp/php-fastcgi.socket
# chgrp websrv /tmp/php-fastcgi.socket
```